# How to correctly implement the delete functionality in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to delete a post of a user. When I click on the `delete` button below the post, it should get delete in real time, like I don't have to refresh the page for it to be deleted.

I have the backend controller ready, but having some confusion in the redux part, like how do I structure my action.

```js
deletePost: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const post = await Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
      if (!post) {
        return res.status(200).json({ error: "No post found"})
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ post })
    } catch(error) {
        return res.json({ error })
    }
  }
```

```js
export const deletePost = (id) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_START" })
    try {
      return await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/${id}/delete`)
    }
    dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS" })


    .........how should i structure this action creator_
```

**post reducer**

```js
const initialState = {
    isAddingPost: false,
    postError: null,
    post: {},
    isFetchingPosts: null,
    hasFetchedPosts: null,
    fetchingPostsError: null,
    postList: []
  }

  const post = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_POST_STARTS":
        return { ...state, isAddingpost: true, postError: null }
      case "ADD_POST_SUCCESS":
        return {
          ...state,
          isAddingpost: false,
          postError: null,
          post: action.data
        }
      case "ADD_POST_ERROR":
        return {
          ...state,
          isAddingpost: false,
          postError: action.data.error,
          post: {}
        }
      case "FETCHING_POSTS_START":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingPosts: true,
          hasFetchedPosts: false,
          fetchingPostsError: null
        }
      case "FETCHING_POSTS_SUCCESS":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingPosts: false,
          hasFetchedPosts: true,
          fetchingPostsError: null,
          postList: action.data.posts
        }
      case "FETCHING_POSTS_ERROR":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingPosts: false,
          hasFetchedPosts: false,
          fetchingPostsError: action.data.error
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  export default post
```

Also, I have another reducer:

```js
const initialState = {
    isFetchingUserPosts: null,
    isFetchedUserPosts: null,
    userPosts: [],
    fetchingUserPostsError: null
  }

  const userPosts = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "FETCHING_USER_POSTS_START":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingUserPosts: true,
          fetchingUserPostsError: null
        }
      case "FETCHING_USER_POSTS_SUCCESS":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingUserPosts: false,
          isFetchedUserPosts: true,
          userPosts: action.data,
          fetchingUserPostsError: null
        }
      case "FETCHING_USER_POSTS_ERROR":
        return {
          ...state,
          isFetchingUserPosts: false,
          isFetchedUserPosts: false,
          userPostsError: action.data.error
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  export default userPosts
```

Comment: A reducer is what would handle deleting it in the app state. Do you have a reducer setup to handle posts in state, specifically `DELETING_POST_SUCCESS`?

Comment: I have reducers for posts list, a single user posts., but not for deleting a post. You mean I should make a `deletePost` reducer? So, okay, when the post gets deleted, the `deletePost` reducer will have the post and store it in the redux store, right?

Comment: Presumably whatever reducer you already have that adds/updates posts would be the same one to remove them (it would be handling the same slice of state, right?). If you have such reducer can you update question with it?

Comment: @YashGadle has the gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have not provided much info about how your data is structured, so I am just going to make some assumptions.
So your reducer should look something like this.

/reducers/post.js

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  //Above two are optional.
  data: [] // These should be your posts.
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'DELETING_POST_START': return {...state, loading: true };
    case 'DELETING_POST_SUCCESS': 
      const posts = state.data.filter(post => post.id !== action.payload.id);
      return {...state, loading: false, error: null ,data: posts}      
    case 'DELETING_POST_FAILURE': return {...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    }
  }
```

Then call the action like so:-

```
export const deletePost = (id) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_START" })
    try {
      const deletedPost = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/${id}/delete`);
      dispatch({ type: "DELETING_POST_SUCCESS", payload: deletedPost });
    }catch(err){//Do something with error}
    ... Rest of the code here
}
```

I have not added failure checks.
Also you mentioned you want real time updates, the above example is not "real-time" as it waits for the server to respond back.
You might want to look into optimistic updates and how to implement them in redux.

Comment: Ignore the initial comment in the answer. I was writing my answer and then you updated your question.

Comment: I would simplify the delete post by using an `array::filter` operation: `const posts = state.posts.filter(post => post.id !== action.payload.id)`. This handles both the creation of a new array and removing the entry with matching id.

Comment: ` const posts = state.data.filter(post => post.id !== action.payload.id)`. Is this line saying, return all the posts except the one that we have deleted? @DrewReese.
Edit: Oh sorry, didn't read your comment.

Comment: @ubuntu7788 More or less, yes. Programmatically we're saying, return a new array with all the elements of this array where this callback function returns true. In this case, where the ids don't match that of the deleted post's id.